# Refresh the content of datatable that is populated from MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I want to refresh the content of datatable that is populated from MySQL DB. So, since DB might be updated in real-time, I want to add Refresh button at the top of the datatable. My code is the following:

```
<div id="refresh">
    <button id="refresh-table">Refresh</button>
    <br>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
         $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#tabbb').dataTable({
              "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
              "aaSorting":[[5, "asc"]],
              "bJQueryUI":true
              });
              $(".refresh_table").click(function() {
                  table=$("#tabbb").dataTable();
                  table.fnPageChange("first",1);                  
              });             
     });
</script>
```

The problem is that when I click of Refresh button, nothing happens.

Comment: So, what is wrong with this question *Mr downvoter*?

Comment: There is something wrong with the head of someone, and not the question. I think that there should be changed something with downvoting permissions. Otherwise, it seems like small children are playing here=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#refresh-table").click(function() {
  var mytable = $('#tabbb').dataTable();
  mytable.fnDraw();
});
```

**Update**

Just noticed that you have a `class` selector for the button, but on the button itself you have an `id`. So you need to change the selector to bind the `click`.

Comment: Another small glitch: `refresh-table` vs. `refresh_table`. Corrected in my answer.